# Is the fundamental group of a compact Riemann surface *after* removing a finite number of points still a Fuchsian group?

Tags: algebraic-topology, riemann-surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $S$ be a compact R.S. admitting a Fuchsian model $\mathbb{H} / \Gamma$. We know that $\pi_1(S) \cong \Gamma$. Let $\mathcal{B} \subseteq S$ be a finite set of points, is $\pi_1(S - \mathcal{B})$ still a Fuchsian group? How is it related to $\Gamma$?

Answer (score 4):

Yes; a hyperbolic surface minus a finite set of points is still a hyperbolic surface. If $S$ has genus $g$ then the fundamental group of $S$ minus a point, as an abstract group, is free on $2g$ generators (the same $2g$ generators generating $\pi_1(S)$, but no longer constrained by their usual relation), and every point removed after that increases the number of free generators by $1$.

Comment: Are you taking "Fuchsian group" to mean "fundamental group of a hyperbolic surface," or "discrete subgroup of $\operatorname{Isom}^+ \mathbb{H}$"? If the latter, I'm having trouble understanding your way of mapping $\pi_1(S - \mathcal{B})$ into $\operatorname{Isom}^+ \mathbb{H}$. If I'm reading your instructions correctly, the loops around the punctures will all get sent to the identity in $\operatorname{Isom}^+ \mathbb{H}$, which seems funny to me.

Comment: @Vectornaut: I think conventions differ slightly on this, but I'm fairly confident that the fundamental group of a hyperbolic surface is always Fuchsian. I'm doing the same thing you're doing in your answer; the fundamental group of any hyperbolic surface acts by deck transformations on its universal cover.

Comment: This makes more sense now. I'd forgotten that a Riemannian metric on a suface, no matter how badly behaved, extends uniquely to a Kähler structure, giving in particular a complex structure (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformization_theorem#Geometric_classification_of_surfaces). So I guess your answer can be more general: a hyperbolic surface minus a finite set of points is still a Riemannian manifold!

Comment: Ah, I've ignored a subtlety, which is how to ensure a hyperbolic metric on the complement that remains complete (as in Lee Mosher's answer)...

Comment: Wait, I was just convinced that the metric on the complement *doesn't* need to be complete! That's what my last comment (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1504283/is-the-fundamental-group-of-a-compact-riemann-surface-after-removing-a-finite/1504308?noredirect=1#comment3065771_1504308) was about.

Comment: Hmm. Well, I'm officially out of my depth here. I admit that in fact I know very little Riemannian or complex geometry.

Comment: I'm hardly an expert here either. It still seems to me that your argument should work for any Riemannian 2-manifold, but there could be subtleties I'm missing. I'll pin this down someday!

Answer (score 2):

The surface $S-B$ has a complete hyperbolic metric of finite area. One can see by a pretty direct construction which generalizes the construction of a hyperbolic metric on $S$ itself. Alternatively, since your question is about a given Riemann Surface structure, one can use the uniformization theorem; since removing the points of $B$ creates "removable singularities", the hyperbolic structure in the deleted neighborhood of such a point must be a cusp, which is complete and of finite area.

It follows (from the construction of the "developing map") that the universal cover $\widetilde{S-B}$ is isometric to the hyperbolic plane $\mathbb{H}^2$, and that once an isometry between them is chosen the deck transformation action of $\pi_1(S-B)$ on $\widetilde{S-B} \approx \mathbb{H}^2$ becomes a Fuchsian group.

A good reference for the non-complex-analytic part of this (complete hyperbolic structures; developing maps; etc.) is [Thurston's book](https://books.google.com/books?id=9kkuP3lsEFQC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Wiliam%20P.%20Thurston&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAGoVChMIjLXIp7jqyAIVxBY-Ch2EYQwQ#v=onepage&q=Wiliam%20P.%20Thurston&f=false) and the [lecture notes that preceded the book](http://library.msri.org/books/gt3m/PDF/3.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

To ask whether $\pi_1(S - \mathcal{B})$ is Fuchsian, you first have to think of it as a subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut} \mathbb{H}$, the automorphism group of $\mathbb{H}$ as a complex manifold.

I assume you want to do this by noting that the universal cover of $S - \mathcal{B}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{H}$, so the action of the fundamental group on the universal cover becomes an action on $\mathbb{H}$ by automorphisms.

In this case, $\pi_1(S - \mathcal{B})$ is indeed Fuchsian. To see why, recall that the fundamental group of a space always acts evenly (properly discontinuously) on the universal cover. In our case, that means $\pi_1(S - \mathcal{B})$ acts evenly on $\mathbb{H}$. It follows that $\pi_1(S - \mathcal{B})$ is a discrete subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut} \mathbb{H}$, as Borthwick argues at the start of Section 2 of their *Introduction to Spectral Theory on Hyperbolic Surfaces*.